# angular js ui-select option repeat not working for object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I am using Angular ui-select. My model & ui-select option array are different. While changing value its not updated and not displaying options. I am storing the selected object Id in "pmpo", I want to show the selected object from the pmptnk object array when loading. But is not working. Some one tell what I am doing wrong.

My object from Model

```
  pmpo:877
  pmptnk:[0:
    632:{id: "632",  pid: "2993", ESID: "9154", lb1: "Undddd", lb2: "219"}
    877:{id: "877",  pid: "2993", ESID: "9154", lb1: "Pcddd", lb2: "29"}
    654:{id: "654",  pid: "2993", ESID: "9154", lb1: "kukuu", lb2: "246"}]
```

In view file

```
 <div ng-if="item.pmptnk.length > 0">
    <ui-select ng-model="item.pmpo" click-out-side="closeThis($event)">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select " search-placeholder="Filter Tanks" 
    uib-tooltip="{{item.pmpo > 0 ? $select.selected.lb1 : 'Select Tank'}}" tab-select="true">
         <span ng-bind="$select.selected.lb1"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="obj.tid as obj in (item.pmptnk[item.pmpo])">
        <span ng-bind="obj.lb1"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
    <ui-select-no-choice>
      No results matched "{{$select.search}}"
    </ui-select-no-choice>
    </ui-select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on your code.I tried it out in different way.
Below is my code snippet:

```
<div ng-if="item.pmptnk.length > 0">
  <ui-select ng-model="item.selected" click-out-side="closeThis($event)">
    <ui-select-match
      placeholder="Select "
      search-placeholder="Filter Tanks"
      uib-tooltip="{{item.pmpo > 0 ? $select.selected.lb1 : 'Select Tank'}}"
      tab-select="true"
    >
      <span ng-bind="$select.selected.lb1"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="obj.tid as obj in (item.pmptnk)">
      <span ng-bind="obj.lb1"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
    <ui-select-no-choice>
      No results matched "{{$select.search}}"
    </ui-select-no-choice>
  </ui-select>
</div>
```

and i changed my model as below:

```
$scope.item = {};
$scope.item.pmpo = 877;
$scope.item.pmptnk = [
  { id: "632", pid: "2993", ESID: "9154", lb1: "Undddd", lb2: "219" },
  { id: "877", pid: "2993", ESID: "9154", lb1: "Pcddd", lb2: "29" },
  { id: "654", pid: "2993", ESID: "9154", lb1: "kukuu", lb2: "246" },
];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.item.pmptnk.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.item.pmptnk[i].id == $scope.item.pmpo) {
    $scope.item.selected = $scope.item.pmptnk[i].tid;
    break;
  }
}
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs of `ui-select-choices`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices), the `repeat` attribute

> Specify the list of items to provide as choices. Syntax is **similar
>   to ngRepeat**.

And according to the [`ng-repeat` doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> It is possible to get ngRepeat to iterate over the properties of an
>   object using the following syntax:
>
> ```
> <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
> ```

So, from this, we can conclude that you should **change your syntax** from this:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="obj.tid as obj in (item.pmptnk[item.pmpo])">
```

**to this**:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="(key, value) in (item.pmptnk[item.pmpo])">
```

where `value` will be `877`, `2993` and so on and `key` will be `id` , `pid` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried as you mentioned. No luck.
<ui-select-choices repeat="(key, value) in (item.pmptnk[item.pmpo])">
 <span ng-bind="lb1"></span>

Comment: Make sure `(item.pmptnk[item.pmpo])` is actually an object.

Comment: In my question, I showed the structure of item.pmptnk . item.pmptnk is an array of object, with the key item.pmpo

Comment: console log:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ui.select/items?p0=Expected%20an%20array%20but%20got%20%27%7B0%7D%27.&p1=%7B%22id%22:%2228263%22,%22client_id%22:%224105%22,%22product_id%22:%223011%22,%22ESID%22:%229180%22,%22lb1%22:%22Low%20Sulfur%20Diesel%22,%22lb2%22:%22510095%22%7D

Comment: This message indicates this can be one of two things: **one**:   the `repeat` attribute syntax is similar to ngRepeat, but definitely it DOES NOT accept the ability to iterate over the properties of an object (not like `ngRepeat`) or **two**: there is some error in the structure of `item.pmptnk[item.pmpo]`. If it would be the first case, these guys of `ui-select` should make that clearer in the docs and you will have to change the structure of `item.pmptnk[item.pmpo]`. If it not anyway you should change the structure of `item.pmptnk[item.pmpo]` in order to get this fixed.

Comment: @Sami, in this case it would be very helpful if you could provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, maybe a plnkr or a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Should not it be ng-repeat instead of just repeat?

```
 <ui-select-choices repeat="obj.tid as obj in (item.pmptnk[item.pmpo])">
```

change this line to the following one

```
<ui-select-choices ng-repeat="obj.tid as obj in (item.pmptnk[item.pmpo])">
```

It will fix the issue hopefully.

Comment: Are you asking or answering?

Comment: @abdulAleem Khan  Repeat will work. The problem is about object array loop. If I change my array to simple object its works.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) it should be `repeat`, not `ng-repeat`